# Fixed header for a text box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

When you reduce the browser window you will see a different layout. When you scroll down the search text box goes up and its not fixed so its not visible. How to make the search text box as fixed when you scroll down? I used the code from another example but the problem is when I implement with my new code its not working. I am trying to work with the data tables search box. I don't know what's wrong in my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/11/

```
$(function() {
        var search = $('.dataTables_filter').detach();
        $('.page-title').before(search);
        search.css('margin-left','0');

        var div = $('.dataTables_filter');
                var start = $(div).offset().top;

                $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
                    var p = $(window).scrollTop();
                    $(div).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
                    $(div).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '0px' : '');
                });
    });
```

Comment: Seems like it's working for me - Firefox in Mac. The box becomes attached to the top of the window as I scroll. It's missing some background so the page content shows through but it seems to do what you need. Is this the code you have problems with?

Comment: try to clean up your fiddle and reduce it to the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem if you expect a solid answer. Also i would suggest looking into css position fixed, in stead of going for the javascript solution.

Comment: I never used datatables, so I can't help you much. What I've seen is that when you resize the window, the CSS `@media` rule changes the table layout to adapt the elements to a small screen. For what concerns the search box, I think you should to search in datatable's js code for a `scroll` event attached to that element, which change the position from `static` to `fixed`. I think this is your search box issue.